# How to prevent error : this old-style function

Tags: c, function-declaration, function-prototypes, parameter-list

I am following a tutorial and my code seems normal but I got a message which says

```
This old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype
```

**code.c :**

```
void viderBuffer()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Thanks you for your help. Sorry if my post is not perfect I am new here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare the function before main (or before referencing it in main) like

```
void viderBuffer( void );
```

And define it also like

```
void viderBuffer( void )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Actually, adding `void` in the parentheses helps me eliminate the warning. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more minimal take than Vlad's -

Declare it like this:

```
void viderBuffer(void) { ... }
```